# Firebase not adding class to Real Time Data Base

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase for login, but I want the user to also be added to the Real-Time Database so I can link the User with further data.

When a user registers, I can see that the user has been added to the authentication section of Firebase, and the user is able to log in but it does not get added to the Real-Time Database.

Here is my code

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
users = db.getReference("Users");

User user = new User();
user.setEmail((editEmail.getText().toString()));
user.setPassword((editPass.getText().toString()));
user.setName((editName.getText().toString()));
user.setPhone(editPhone.getText().toString());


users.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
    .setValue(user)
```

I also set an onSuccess/fail listener with Toasts letting me know if it failed or not. And neither of the toasts execute. I do have read/write enabled on my DB.

Comment: Have you tried to add a complete listener to the `setValue()` operation and see if you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, and nothing prints out. I tried a log above the last line aswell (users.child(...)) and it prints fine

Comment: Is your onComplete even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't think so, I think that is the issue but I can't see why. If functions in the previous line get triggered.

Comment: Are you sure you have internet connection on the device?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, in the lines above what I have shown, the textview information is uploaded to Firebase as authentication, and I can see that in firebase. I can also login using that information. But for some reason it does not add to real-time database

Answer (score 0):

Define Variable.

```
  private DatabaseReference userRef;
```

in OnCreate method.

```
userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
```

in a signup button

```
String getUserName = usernameEditText.getText.toString;
String getBio = bioEditText.getText.toString;
```

//and you should use the validates

```
if(getUserName.equals("")
   {
    usernameEditText.setError("Field Required");
   }
   else if(getBio.equals("")
   {
    bioEditText.setError("Field Required");
   }

   else
    {
                            
    final HashMap<String , Object> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
                        profileMap.put("uid" , FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        profileMap.put("name" , getUserName);
                        profileMap.put("status" , getBio);
    
    
    
    
     userRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                        .updateChildren(profileMap)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                            {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful())
                                                {
                                                    Log.v("Profile Updated" , "Profile Updated Successfully");
                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this , MainActivity.class);
                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                    finish();
        
                                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Your profile Info has been updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
```

}